# Modifying a style attribute in Selenium with execute_script, but the attribute's value doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Using: Selenium with PhantomJS in Python

I need to set a style attribute of an input tag to '' because it is set to "display:None" which prevents me from filling the input with send_keys in Selenium.

I am using execute_script to achieve this. execute_script runs, but the style attribute remains unaltered. Why isn't PhantomJS changing the style attribute?

**HTML with style attribute I want to remove**:

```
<input type="password" size="10" id="navbar_password" name="vb_login_password" tabindex="102" class="textbox" style="display: none;">
```

**Python Selenium script:**

Why isn't the style attribute's value being changed by execute_script?

```
password = driver.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0]['style'] = arguments[1]", password, '')

print(password.get_attribute("style"))

//display:none;
```

Comment: **Update**: I tried changing various attributes on the username input field, and it worked every time, but the password input field can't be altered...I know it has something to do with the display: None attribute, but I have no idea how to remedy it if I can't fix it.

Perhaps I should try deleting that element from the dom and then inserting a copy without that style attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
password = driver.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password")

password = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block'; return arguments[0];", password)

print(password.value_of_css_property("display"))

#now you can set value using send_keys
password.send_keys("your value");
```

Hope it helps...:)